# c++ convert cv::Mat from CV_8U to CV_32F

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm having an issue with OpenCV (Assertion Failure) as the image is being loaded as CV_8U when it should be loaded as CV_32F.

So how can i convert from CV_8U to CV_32F?

Many Thanks.

Comment: there is Mat::convertTo() , but if that's a followup to your BOW question, then you're wrong. you don't need float images there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [convertTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto)

```
input.convertTo(output, CV_32F)
```